# Django and technical fields

Tags: python, django, django-orm, dry

I'm building a data model. I want that each model has some technical fields like: `created` and `updated`. I don't like to add those fieds to each model (you know...DRY).

I tried to build a parent class with the `created` and `updated` fields, and inherit it in the other models, but Django's ORM does not put `created` and `updated` fields in the table of the model, instead it creates another table for the two fields and link it to the model via foreign key. That is not what I want.

Is there a feasible way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it multiple time :

```
class TimeStampedModel(models.Model):
    """
    An abstract base class model that provides self-
    updating 'created' and 'modified' fields
    """

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

And for other models :

```
from core.models import TimeStampedModel

class MyClass(TimeStampedModel):
    """
    CLASS LAMBDA
    """
    field = models.DecimalField(verbose_name=u"Name", max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    field2 = models.CharField(verbose_name=u"Name 2", max_length=200)
```

Now in `ipython` :

```
from bundle.models.my_class import MyClass
item = MyClass.objects.first()
print item.created
```

Now `created` is set when the entry is `created` (`auto_now_add=True`) and `modified` is when you .... `modified` your entry (`auto_now=True`).

The magic is, its an abstract class ([doc here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes)):

> Abstract base classes are useful when you want to put some common information into a number of other models. You write your base class and put abstract=True in the Meta class. This model will then not be used to create any database table. Instead, when it is used as a base class for other models, its fields will be added to those of the child class.

Comment: its work for multiple parent.. its an abstract class